# What do you call the little rings that hold the cord in a fishing rod?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the little rings that hold the cord in a fishing rod?

[image]

I did some research and the rings don't seem to have a name, but I doubt we call them rings. Is there any word that may refer to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called *guides*. [Here's a reference site](https://www.mudhole.com/Components-Rod-Building/rod-guides-components) so you can see it in context.

Answer (score 1):

In any other context, a ring like that would be called an 'eyelet'.

Terminology seems to vary a little between different parts of the UK and USA, but the one on the end would be called a 'tip ring' or 'tip eye' depending on location, while the intermediate rings seem mostly to be called 'guide rings'.